# use of malloc in contiki programs

Tags: c, stm32, contiki

Consider the following contiki program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"contiki.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *mem;
static int x;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(test, "test");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&test);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(test, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();
  printf("before malloc\n");
  mem=(char*)malloc(10);
  for(x=0;x<10;x++)
     mem[x]=x+1;
  printf("after malloc\n");
  PROCESS_END();
}
```

when this program is compiled for native/z1/wismote/cooja it executes perfectly fine and both the printf statements are executed, but when compiled for mbxxx target, and then executed on hardware, only the first printf statements is executed and the code gets stuck in the malloc. Any guess or reason behind this behaviour? I am also attaching the GDB trace here.

```
(gdb) mon reset init
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000efc msp: 0x20000500
(gdb) b test.c:16
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8000ec8: file test.c, line 16.
(gdb) b test.c:17
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8000ece: file test.c, line 17.
(gdb) b test.c:18
Breakpoint 3 at 0x8000ed8: file test.c, line 18.
(gdb) load
Loading section .isr_vector, size 0x84 lma 0x8000000
Loading section .text, size 0xc5c4 lma 0x8000084
Loading section .data, size 0x660 lma 0x800c648
Start address 0x8000084, load size 52392
Transfer rate: 15 KB/sec, 8732 bytes/write.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.

Breakpoint 1, process_thread_test (process_pt=0x2000050c <test+12>, ev=129 '\201', data=0x0) at test.c:16
16      printf("before malloc\n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, process_thread_test (process_pt=0x2000050c <test+12>, ev=<optimized out>, 
    data=<optimized out>) at test.c:17
17  mem=(char*)malloc(10);
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
Default_Handler () at ../../cpu/stm32w108/hal/micro/cortexm3/stm32w108/crt-stm32w108.c:87
87  {
(gdb) bt
#0  Default_Handler () at ../../cpu/stm32w108/hal/micro/cortexm3/stm32w108/crt-stm32w108.c:87
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x08000440 in _malloc_r ()
#3  0x08000ed4 in process_thread_test (process_pt=0x2000050c <certificate_check+12>, ev=<optimized out>, 
    data=<optimized out>) at test.c:17
#4  0x0800272c in call_process (p=0x20000500 <test>, ev=<optimized out>, data=<optimized out>)
    at ../../core/sys/process.c:190
#5  0x080028e6 in process_post_synch (p=<optimized out>, ev=ev@entry=129 '\201', data=<optimized out>)
    at ../../core/sys/process.c:366
#6  0x0800291a in process_start (p=<optimized out>, arg=arg@entry=0x0) at ../../core/sys/process.c:120
#7  0x08002964 in autostart_start (processes=<optimized out>) at ../../core/sys/autostart.c:57
#8  0x08001134 in main () at ../../platform/mbxxx/./contiki-main.c:210
(gdb)
```

Comment: Seems like you are using a variant of Doug Lea's `malloc `implementation on your system. You will need a version of the C library with debug symbols to find out where inside the `malloc` function it is getting stuck. This is likely a system specific problem, and might even be specific to your installation, so there is very little someone outside of that specific development community can do to help you. Good luck!

Comment: @jxh this was tagged with 'contiki', which is an embedded OS.

Comment: @errordeveloper: I'm sorry, does that mean you believe my advice was wrong, and that the problem is not system specific or not installation specific?

Comment: I believe this can be sorted out by modifying some linker script parameters, but I don't know how to or which one. @jxh appreciate your advice about the debug symbols, I've been trying hell and heaven but with no progress.

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh... Finally figured out the problem. This particular problem was there because stm32w108 was not configured to use dynamic memory.

All that was needed to be done was, to open the the following file:
contiki-2.7/cpu/stm32w108/hal/micro/cortexm3/stm32w108/crt-stm32w108.c and add #define USE_HEAP at the top of the file or before the _sbrk implementation! The heap size can also be modified here, not from the linker script, although the stack size

**A side note:** *It is a really bad idea to use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems, so avoid it! Its filthy trust me! Eventually I will also remove any dynamic memory allocation references! :)*

Comment: I am trying to build a Contiki port for lpc1347, I did a similar mistake too when i was trying to run a basic LED blinking program, in the end i had to remove all the `printf` statements. Can you please elaborate how does `#define USE_HEAP` solved your problem.

Comment: Your case is slightly different I guess. I never had any problems with printf, rather it was an issue with the dynamic memory allocation. Generally in many embedded platforms dynamic memory allocation is not enabled in the c runtime, or put simply the heap management is just not there. In such cases calling malloc leads to a runtime error. Another important thing to note is that the c runtime is closely associated with the processor architecture. I was using stm32, which is not the same as yours, so it is quite possible that the USE_HEAP switch may not exist at all in your code.