# Using printf causes error

Tags: c, arm, stm32

I'm trying to configure an STM32f10X project to be able to use the `printf` functionm, after setting all the needed function , the comiler throws an error which I can't understand . the error occurs only when I use the `printf` here is the error message that I get for  `printf(" hello");`

```
d:/armtc/gccarm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: section .ARM.exidx loaded at [08009ee4,08009eeb] overlaps section .data loaded at [08009ee4,0800a8e7]
```

my question is what does this error message mean ? and how can I solve it

Comment: Did you check if you defined `#define USE_HEAP` anywhere in the  program: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872214/use-of-malloc-in-contiki-programs).